# Delphi interface generic function returning TobjectList<T>

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Why does this not work? I get a E2511 Type parameter 'T' must be a class type?

```
type
  IBaseProvider<T> = Interface
    function GetAll: TObjectList<T>;
  end;

type
  TCar = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IBaseProvider<TVehicle>)
    function GetAll: TObjectList<TVehicle>;
  end;

implementation

function TCar.GetAll: TObjectList<TVehicle>;
begin
  // do something with Objectlist
  Result := ObjectList
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter T of [`TObjectList<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList) is constrained to be a class.

```
type
  TObjectList<T: class> = class(TList<T>)
    ....
  end;
```

You need to declare a constraint that implies this on your type. For example you can declare the same constraint:

```
type
  IBaseProvider<T: class> = Interface
    function GetAll: TObjectList<T>;
  end;
```

Or you could declare a stronger constraint, so long as the `TObjectList<T>` constraint is met. If you don't want to constrain your parameter, then you'd need to use `TList<T>`.

If you are not familiar with generic constraints, the documentation should fill in the gaps : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics

Comment: thank you, David. But what about TDictionary. in java I can write:  HashMap<String, IBaseProvider<?>> dataproviders = new HashMap<String, IBaseProvider<?>>();. How to write in delphi??

Comment: That's a different question. Let's finish this question first.